# Converting huge dataframe into a multidimensional array

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame with 10000 rows and 2048 columns. I am trying to convert this into a multi-dimensional array in the dimensions of 10000[rows]x32x32x2. 
Here each row data should be converted into 32x32x2

```
> For ex: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
2 a b c d e f g h i  j 
3 q k l m j g t y u  r 
4 a e t i o p l m n  s 
5
> 
> I want to create 10000 arrays with dimension of 32x32x2 here for ex
> 5x5x2 
1 array 
a b c d e 
f g h i j
> 
> 2nd array 
q k l m j 
g t y u r
```

I am fairly new to R building models.
Please can you anyone help me.

Comment: See `?array`. If your data is named `dd`, probably just need something like `array(dd, dim = c(1000, 32, 32, 2)`.

Comment: Correction: If you have your data as a data frame, `as.matrix()` first can be helpful. Consider `dd <- data.frame(sapply(1:2048, function(x) rnorm(1000))); str(array(as.matrix(dd), dim = c(1000, 32, 32, 2)))`